# JS: Array defined or undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data like,

```
data = [cluster1:skill1, cluster1:skill2, cluster1:skill3, cluster2, cluster3:skill4, cluster4:skill5];
```

From the above lookup I am modeling data like below structure using the code I tried,

```
modelData 
    [0]: 
        Main: cluster1
        Sub: skill1,skill2,skill3

    [1]:
        Main: cluster2
        Sub: //want this to be empty but now it is undefined
    [2]:
        Main: cluster3
        sub: skill4,skill5
// code JS
    dataMap = data().reduce(function (map, item) {
        var key = item.split(':')[0];
        map[key] = map[key] || [];
        map[key].push(item.split(':')[1]);
        return map;
    }, {});

    modelData(Object.keys(dataMap).map(function(key) {
            return {
                Main: ko.observable(key),
                Sub: ko.observableArray(dataMap[key])
        };
    }));
```

All I want is if an lookup entry doesnot contains : (colon), then that entry should be considered as Main value and sub array should be empty rather than undefined. I am confused that how can I check that sub array is undefined or defined.

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: please add some real data. please have a look here: [mcve]

Comment: Can you format you data to reflect actual content in it.. at the moment its not even valid data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused that how can I check that sub array is undefined or defined.

Looking at your code All you need is to replace this line

```
 map[key].push(item.split(':')[1]); // your element at [1] might be undefined
```

With

```
 map[key].push(item.split(':')[1] || []); // if [1] is undefined push [] empty array
```

You need to check if the data you are trying to push is undefined or not. You can do that by using `||` operator.

Comment: This is really awesome!  I tried, It is adding empty value with array length 1. I dont even want this empty value pushed array. I just want this array to be empty with length 0. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: @MJSuriya replace `""` with `[]` .. Let me know if that is what you are looking for

Comment: That's amazing ! Thanks a lot

Comment: @MJSuriya glad to help!!